# error occurred "java: cannot access java.util.function.Function class file for java.util.function.Function not found " in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am having the above issue once am running the code. I have changed my language level into 8 and added maven properties into the POM file. But still having this issue. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Hello Shani. Without any code it is very difficult to troubleshoot this issue. Please share the code relevant to your issue.

Comment: i have sorted my issue.yes it might be the case with the dependency didnt bind properly  but what i did was i already created the new projects and recode because i wan in very beginning in my project and its work for me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes as like above comment it's quite difficult to solve problem without any error log or code so if possible please add it.
- Else where as per my experience i thought that it's occurred in case where your JDK dependency not bind properly with your project.
- In such case you're not able to use that library inside your project. For that go inside "Project settings" inside your IDE and check dependency bind properly(like following image) or not if not then do it first.

[image]

Comment: yes it might be the case but what i did was i already created the new projects and recode because i wan in very beginning in my project and its work for me.Thank you very much

Comment: It's my pleasure & Thanks a lot @Shani today i achieve first milestone 1k reputation with your last upvote :)